# Jenkins on Solaris 10 64 bit

Tags: java, jenkins, installation, solaris-10

I am trying to upgrade my Jenkins on a Solaris SPARC machine. I have been using Jenkins version 1.528 and the java version is "1.6.0_65".

I tried to install 1.565.1 on this server, I was able to start it using "java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8086"

```
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8086
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:16 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:18 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:37 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 54927
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:37 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 54928
Aug 13, 2014 2:52:37 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

but the homepage never loads on browser. I see there is something listening on the port but the connnetion is in CLOSE_WAIT status.

```
bash-3.2$ lsof -i |grep 8086
java      26329 acs    7u  IPv4 0x3018556b840        0t0  TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
java      26329 acs  105u  IPv4 0x30278e93900        0t0  TCP server:8086->user-machine:54670 (ESTABLISHED)
java      26329 acs  750u  IPv4 0x300b9af9900        0t0  TCP server:8086->user-machine:54671 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java      26329 acs  751u  IPv4 0x301ab4f0080        0t0  TCP server:8086->user-machine:54672 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

I tried other version 1.532 and it worked but it did not work for 1.534

I tried the same version 1.565.3 on a Linux server and it worked there, It had java version "1.7.0_45". Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: can you login to server and try to `curl` from `localhost` ?

Comment: I dont have curl on this box, I am not a admin so cannot add it

Comment: well then just browse it using a web browser or `wget`

Comment: Browsing with web browser, we dont get any response from the server, I am not sure how to enable logs for jenkins without it starting up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not fixed, I have opened a JIRA ticket on Jenkins forum

[JENKINS-24357](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24357?filter=-2)

There are a few related tickets as well

Answer (score 1):

We have got the same problem on Solaris 11.1.
SunOS XXXXX 5.11 11.1 sun4v sparc sun4v

We are so far using 5.32.1 stable working. 5.80.3 not working.

There is no respond on wget. We are using default port 8080 and neither on wget nor on browser a connection can be established.

Comment: We are working with a different context root. There is a jetty error on startup, that context root can't be set. Maybe this is the original problem?